# How to lower the resolution of a laptop monitor?

Tags: software-recommendation, dell, display

I am using laptop dell inspiron 5421. Now with an accident the 1/3rd of my left side screen is damaged. Now I was wondering is there any way so that I could shrink the screen size to other 2/3rd of my laptop?

Comment: A lower resolution will still be full screen but you get less pixels per inch ;) I doubt it is possible. Time for a new laptop or to add an external screen and use it as an in-house system (and not for using it on the road)

Comment: @Rinzwind It is possible using xrandr

Answer (score 0):

It is possible by using `xrandr` util

First execute xrandr

```
$ xrandr

Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
eDP1 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 282mm x 165mm
   1920x1080      60.0*+   59.9     40.0  
   1680x1050      60.0     59.9  
   1600x1024      60.2  
   1400x1050      60.0  
   1280x1024      60.0  
   1440x900       59.9  
   1280x960       60.0  
   1360x768       59.8     60.0  
   1152x864       60.0  
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   640x480        59.9
```

You will see current resolutions.

You need to add another one, that will cut some pixels from both sides of your display.

For example: I'm using 1920x1080, 1920 is vertical resolution. If I want to cut 200 pixels (100 from both sides) I should add 1720x1080.

---

Adding this new resolution:

```
$ cvt 1720 1080 60
# 1720x1080 59.98 Hz (CVT) hsync: 67.18 kHz; pclk: 154.25 MHz
Modeline "1720x1080_60.00"  154.25  1720 1832 2008 2296  1080 1083 1093 1120 -hsync +vsync
```

Now copy output starting from word "Modeline", and run this:

```
xrandr --newmode "1720x1080_60.00"  154.25  1720 1832 2008 2296  1080 1083 1093 1120 -hsync +vsync
```

Now run `xrandr` command, and look at the seconds line:

> eDP1 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 282mm x 165mm

eDP1 is the name of connected output. Enter it to the next command

```
xrandr --addmode eDP1 "1720x1080_60.00"
```

Now run `xrandr` to check that new resolution successfully added.

```
$ xrandr

Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
eDP1 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 282mm x 165mm
   1920x1080      60.0*+   59.9     40.0  
   1680x1050      60.0     59.9  
   1600x1024      60.2  
   1400x1050      60.0  
   1280x1024      60.0  
   1440x900       59.9  
   1280x960       60.0  
   1360x768       59.8     60.0  
   1152x864       60.0  
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   640x480        59.9  
   1720x1080_60.00   59.7
```

---

Now run `arandr` command.

[image]

Do right click on your output, in my case it is eDP1, then `Resolution`, and pick your new resolution. It should do what you want.

---

Everything was taken from [Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/Resolution#Adding_undetected_resolutions), please read it if you have any doubts.

Comment: But this thing will shrink screen from both side, right? not just from 1 side ..

Comment: @user139820 use can try, 'xrandr --pos 100x0'. I'm answering from phone, Will update answer later

Comment: Please update the answer

Comment: As I understand `xrandr --pos` works only for Dual Monitor. I'll try to find solution and write you later.

Comment: http://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.5/doc/man/man1/xrandr.1.html  , may be `--panning` has something to do with. Can you check please?

Comment: @user139820 I checked it. This key for another use case. I'm still searching for solution